# Regex match alphanumeric in any part of query

Tags: c#, regex

Can someone help me with creating a Regex function that would help get the following ? The problem is the numbers/alphanumeric may come up in part of the query as well.

```
string = 1942 ng12 bagel cream;
output = 1942 ng12
```

Comment: Can you add more details about what you want to do? Give a sample input and your expected output. Btw, what have you tried so far?

Comment: If a provided answer solves your issue. Might want to accept that answer to give the author credit. Just saying.

Comment: @James Shaw I did that.. for some reason my post got deleted. Sorry am new to this.. is there any other way to give an author credit?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, but you may get multiple answers.

```
([^ ]*[0-9]+[^ ]*)
```

It will also work for things like this:

```
string = 1942 bagel ng12 cream
output = 1942 ng12
```